# Correcting /var permissions to it's original state

Tags: permissions

Ok I just royally screwed up my `/var` folder's permissions.

I thought I was inside `/var/www` and did a `chmod xxx ./*` on the parent folder /var instead.

Now all the permissions inside `/var` are messed up. What can I do to correct it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My `/var/` holds the folllowing files:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 2012-04-05 04:51 backups
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root  4096 2012-04-03 07:06 cache
drwxrwsrwt 31 root whoopsie 4096 2012-04-03 07:06 crash
drwxr-xr-x 31 root root  4096 2012-04-03 07:06 lib
drwxrwsr-x  2 root staff 4096 2008-04-15 05:53 local
lrwxrwxrwt  3 root root     9 2012-04-03 07:09 lock -> /run/lock
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root  4096 2012-05-15 04:40 log
drwxrwsrwt  2 root mail  4096 2010-07-23 07:32 mail
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 2009-02-12 08:08 opt
lrwxr-xr-x 15 root root   520 2012-05-15 07:55 run -> /run
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root  4096 2010-07-23 07:20 spool
drwxrwxrwt  2 root root  4096 2012-05-14 14:20 tmp
```

From this you should be able to set permissions back to what they need to be.

Comment: Thanks, I had another installation but triple checking is always good. :D Now, I have tried nearly everything to get `drwxrwsrwt`on `/var/crash` but the closest I can get is `drwsrwsrwt`. What does the chmod permission number look like for the crash folder?

Comment: You got me there; never noticed user does not have 's' set :P Should not be a problem though. I believe it was `2000` that sets it to a system (setgid bit) (http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/chmod.1.asp)

Comment: This just helped me resolve a nasty mysql wont start problem. I reset my /var permissions to your and it magically started.

Comment: You are welcome @opensourcechris Thanks for the upvote (if that was you ;) )

Comment: It was me. You are welcome!

Comment: The permissions `drwxrwsrwt` can be reproduced by doing `chmod a+w,g+s,o+t`