# I changed my var folder permission to 777 do I have to re-install the system

Tags: permissions, directory

I just accidentally changed my var folder permission to 777 and it's sub folders. Do I have to re-install my system? and as far until now it didn't made any trouble for me.

Comment: Will your system boot? What do you mean by `as far until now it didn't made any trouble for me`?

Comment: I mean it boots and there is no problem with my system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a 'will it work?' standpoint, everything should be completely fine and your system should function normally.

That being said, now all processes/users/anything will have complete access to anything inside the `/var` directory, which will make your system **MUCH** less secure.

If security is not an issue for you, then you can leave your system the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

The default setting is drwxr-xr-x. To restore this, use `cd /` then `sudo chmod 755 var`.

Comment: I know this and I restored some of it's sub-folders too. but I'm still afraid if it makes troubles in future.

Comment: Just to be extra clear, the default setting for `/var` is 755. This isn't necessarily true for all its files and subdirs.

Comment: I know thanks I changed back based on this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/137181/correcting-var-permissions-to-its-original-state)